# How to convert to XMl string to java object or json object

Tags: java

I have a XML string, I want to convert to XML to java object.

```html
<XMLRequest>
    <RequestAction>Modify</RequestAction>
    <MerchantDetail>
        <CloverID>10</CloverID>
        <MerchantNumber>111111</MerchantNumber>
        <Platform>N</Platform>
        <DBAName>Test_306</DBAName>
        <LegalName>Test_306</LegalName>
        <Address1>Fountain road</Address1>
        <City>Vista</City>
        <State>Boulder</State>
        <Zip>1518580</Zip>
        <Country>US</Country>
        <PhoneNumber>1234567890</PhoneNumber>
        <Email>test@gmail.com</Email>
        <Contact>Test_306</Contact>
        <Reseller>DevelopersUS</Reseller>
        <MCCCode>7394</MCCCode>
        <Currency>USD</Currency>
        <TAEncryptionType>0001</TAEncryptionType>
        <GroupID>10001</GroupID>
        <SupportPhone>1234567890</SupportPhone>
        <ABAAccountNumber>000000000000000</ABAAccountNumber>
        <DDAAccountNumber>***********3770</DDAAccountNumber>
    </MerchantDetail>
    <CardTypes>
        <CardType CardName = "MASTER">
            <SENUMBER />
            <AlphaID>1234</AlphaID>
            <ServiceType>F</ServiceType>
        </CardType>
        <CardType CardName = "VISA">
            <SENUMBER />
            <AlphaID />
            <ServiceType />
        </CardType>
    </CardTypes>
</XMLRequest>
```

I tried using below code. And also created respective pojos as well. But I am getting below error. Please help, what I missed.

**Code:**

```java
ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
Request value = xmlMapper.readValue(xmlContent, Request.class);
System.out.println(xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(value));
```

> Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.ContentReference
> com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory._createContentReference(java.lang.Object)'
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory.createParser(XmlFactory.java:492)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3677)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3645)
> at
> com.clover.myspringbootapp.example.XmlToJsonObject.main(XmlToJsonObject.java:25)

Comment: Which jackson libs are using? Versions?

Comment: <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.14.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
      <version>2.14.2</version>
    </dependency>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using library such as JAXB and write class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "XMLRequest")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class XMLRequest {
 @XmlElement(name = "RequestAction")
private String requestAction;

@XmlElement(name = "MerchantDetail")
private MerchantDetail merchantDetail;

@XmlElementWrapper(name = "CardTypes")
@XmlElement(name = "CardType")
private CardType[] cardTypes;
```

}

and MerchantDetail  class

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MerchantDetail {

@XmlElement(name = "CloverID")
private int cloverID;

@XmlElement(name = "MerchantNumber")
private int merchantNumber;

@XmlElement(name = "Platform")
private String platform;

@XmlElement(name = "DBAName")
private String dbaName;

@XmlElement(name = "LegalName")
private String legalName;

@XmlElement(name = "Address1")
private String address1;

@XmlElement(name = "City")
private String city;

@XmlElement(name = "State")
private String state;

@XmlElement(name = "Zip")
private String zip;

@XmlElement(name = "Country")
private String country;

@XmlElement(name = "PhoneNumber")
private String phoneNumber;

@XmlElement(name = "Email")
private String email;

@XmlElement(name = "Contact")
private String contact;

@XmlElement(name = "Reseller")
private String reseller;

@XmlElement(name = "MCCCode")
private int mccCode;

@XmlElement(name = "Currency")
private String currency;

@XmlElement(name = "TAEncryptionType")
private String taEncryptionType;

@XmlElement(name = "GroupID")
private int groupID;

@XmlElement(name = "SupportPhone")
private String supportPhone;

@XmlElement(name = "ABAAccountNumber")
private String abaAccountNumber;

@XmlElement(name = "DDAAccountNumber")
private String ddaAccountNumber;

// add getter and setters
```

}

Like wise CardType class

then

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(XMLRequest.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
    XMLRequest xmlRequest = (XMLRequest) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("input.xml"));
```

Comment: I am getting cardName as null, even I have added @XmlElement

Comment: Got it, I need to add @XmlAttribute, It worked.